# Sorting arrays difficulty

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to process data from an input file which has max. 100,000 lines like the following:

> 2014269619 Sally Clare Smith Female 95

These are the ID number, name (2 or 3 words), gender and exam score. Separated by tabs.

I must create an array of max. 100,000 length for each of these attributes. Also, the first number within the input file will be the number of lines in that file. So, I create arrays with length 100,000.

Once I set up an array, I would use a given function to sort the names by alphabetical string order (ascending) of Name and then put these into an output file. However, I am not required to use this specific function.

My challenge here is that although the given function sorts the names, it does not move the ID, gender, and score together with the names, resulting in a useless database.

I have tried doing to first part (setting up arrays) in the following way but it seems wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void  ordering_sort( double  x[],  int  length)
{   
    int  i,  j,  k;
    double  t;

    for  (i=0;  i<length-1;  ++i)  {        
        k = i;       //find next smallest elm, x[k]

        for  (j=i+1;  j< length;  ++j)
            if  (x[k] > x[j])  k = j;

        //swap x[i] with x[k] 
        t = x[i];   x[i] = x[k];  x[k] = t;   
    }
}


int main () {

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("input.txt");
    fout.open("output.txt");

    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Fail to open inout.txt" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int ID [100000];
    string name [100000];
    string gender [100000];
    int score [100000];

    int y = 0;

    // In the following part, I am trying to extract the information into the different arrays,
    // one by one, increasing the number of the element from 0 up till x. 
    // Problem is that getline does not work for int arrays but I must use int.

    for (int y=0 ; y<x, y++) {
        getline(fin, ID [y], '\t'); // This does not work.
        getline(fin, name [y], '\t');
        getline(fin, gender [y], '\t');
        getline(fin, score [y], '\t'); //This does not work either.
        break;
    }

    ordering_sort( name,  int  length)

    // trying to use the function, which will not work as of now
```

Basically, I would need help with:

- extracting the data from input file into the arrays making sure that
  sorting will apply to every line not just individual    arrays (so
  whole lines will be sorted)
- finding a way to make getline work for int arrays
- I shall output the data into an output file but that should not be a
  problem.
- All of this must be done using arrays and without using structures,
  vectors, maps.

Other libraries are fine.

Comment: "All of this must be done using arrays and without using structures, vectors, maps, other libraries" That's a bizarre restriction. Can you explain why this constraint is enforced?

Comment: No other libraries? Tell your instructor to take a flying leap, as you'll be busy for awhile implementing the sys calls needed for the *file IO*. He's certainly from academia. The `std::getline()` you mentioned just two items is part of the same library, btw, so I guess thats out too.

Comment: "This does not work" is not an error description.

Comment: You are right, apologies for not giving you the exact compiler error. The issue is though, as describen above, that you cannot use getline with int arrays only with strings, and that is the problem above.

Comment: Don't sort the names; sort an index array instead with a custom comparator concept. The resulting index array can then be used to index *all* your arrays equally.

Comment: The way to do the sorting is to create another array of int's. Call this the index array. Fill the array with 0, 1, 2, ... n - 1. Sort that array using it to index your scores (i.e. `if (score[index[i]] < score[index[j]]) swap(index[i],index[j]);`). Finally use the sorted index array to reorder the other arrays (that's the part I always find hard to get right).

Comment: @john Its like deja-vu all over again =P Save for the part about reordering anything. Just use the index array to dump *all* of the source array elements by index, one "row" at a time. you don't need to reorder *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, this code is not valid standard C++, it relies on compiler extensions (in particular gcc style ones)

```
int ID [x];
string name [x];
string gender [x];
int score [x];
```

So, to make it valid standard code, you would have to use `new`. But I'm going to ignore that, as I expect your shown code compiles and that's good enough for this project.

> - finding a way to make getline work for int arrays

Since the items are separated by tabs (from what I can tell), all you actually need to do is:

```
cin >> ID[y]; 
getline(cin, name[y], '\t');
... 
cin >> score[y];
```

As for the sorting part, there is two solutions:

1. As suggested in a comment, you sort an index-table.
2. In your sort function, when you swap, you swap all the items.

The sorting of the index table would be something like this:

```
if (score[index[i]] > score[index[j]]) swap(index[i], index[j]);
```

The swap everything apprach would be something like this:

```
if (score[i] > score[j])
{
     swap(ID[i], ID[j]);
     swap(name[i], name[j]);
     swap(gender[i], gender[j]);
     swap(score[i], score[j]);
}
```